# IE11 nested flexbox issue with parent table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

We have a scenario with nested flexbox and whose parent is a table. Although in chrome trhis behaves as expected, in IE-11 the flexboxes do not wrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/arnabgh/qg5rojc9/3/

We cannot make the table-layout:fixed. Is there any other better way to fix the same?

```
        <table style="border:1px solid red;width:50%";>
     <tr>
       <td>
            <div class="layout flex">
             <div class="con flex">
               <label>First name</label>
               <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="con flex">
               <label>Last name</label>
                 <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="con flex">
               <label>Address 1</label>
                 <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="con flex">
               <label>Address 2</label>
                  <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="con flex">
               <label>City</label>
                  <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="con flex">
               <label>State</label>
                 <div class="field-item"><input /></div>
              </div>
            </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The CSS is as folllows-

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.layout.flex {
    display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.con {
  width:auto;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;

}

label {
  width: 120px;
}

.field-item {
  flex: 1;

}
```

Comment: This question lacks context. You say you can't use table-layout:fixed - but what other possible restrictions are there? Presumably you have more than just this one cell in the table? So how is it allowed or not allowed to affect that? (And why is there a table in the first place? At least what you have shown here doesn't look like tabular data ...)

Answer (score 0):

the horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells, in your example your table only has one column (td).
So if you want to use the layout-table: fixed you have to define more than a "td" and to test just give them different widths

Comment: in IE you need anyway the flex prefixes